# Can't seem to create an Xcode extension

Tags: ios, xcode

I've tried creating an Xcode extension following the instructions in:

1. [creating a source editor extension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcodekit/creating_a_source_editor_extension)
2. [testing your source editor extension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcodekit/testing_your_source_editor_extension)

But when running the testing instance of Xcode, the extension doesn't appear under the Editor menu nor anywhere else.

What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

`Extension` requires a host program, so if you only create `Extension` there is no way to see the options. You can try adding it in an existing project like this:

[image]

I hope useful to you

#### Update：

After the `Extension` is created successfully, the test looks like this

[image]

Comment: According to the article in the second link i added - you can test it in an Xcode testing instance but i can't see it there. Clicking the plus sign like you suggested will add a new target and not the one i already implemented...

Comment: Sorry, you may have misunderstood. Keep in mind that extensions and hosts are paired, and there is no way to create extensions without a host. Then if you first create an extension, it means that it is already in the host program, you can test it directly, and the screenshot is updated.